# Qt string termination

Tags: c++, string, qt

I'm trying to parse a payload in qt.
The payload is a const u_char *, and I also have its length. The payload may contain null characters.

I would like to do various operations with the payload, such as finding if it contains a given string, using regex on it, etc, which is why using a QString seemed easier to manipulate it.

So I tried QString s((const char*) payload); but this constructor doesn't allow null characters within the string.

Hence my questions :

- Is it possible to create a QString that contains a null character ?
- Should I use another object instead of a QString, and if so, which one (one that would still allow to search within it and match it against a regex ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you care to look at the QString class documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `QRegExp` (or `QRegularExpression` in Qt5), you need to use a `QString`. To construct a `QString` from raw bytes, you need to specify the character encoding to do so. If your payload carries **UTF-8 text**, use [`QString::fromUtf8`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#fromUtf8) which also takes a size parameter. Then, the data may also contain a null character which will be part of the string instead of terminate it:

```
QString str = QString::fromUtf8(data, length);
```

If you want to use regular expressions on **binary data**, don't use `QRegExp`. Use `boost::regex` or `std::regex` instead, they handle binary data well. They can operate on `std::string` (but are generic), which can be constructed also with a data-and-length constructor similar to the above code:

```
string str { data, length };
```

Comment: Are you sure ? If I do QString s = QString::fromUtf8((const char*) payload, size_payload); I still sometimes get size_payload != s.size()

Comment: @jbaw1 That's because UTF-8 characters are not always single bytes. As I said: Only do this if the payload actually is UTF-8. Otherwise use `std::regex` with `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a `std::stringstream`, this object can contain null characters and do a number of different operations.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/stringstream/